# Visual C++: linking takes ages in release mode

Tags: visual-studio-2008, linker

For an unknown reason, the linking step in my C++ app step takes just a few seconds in debug builds but over a minute in release mode. Does anyone have any idea if it's likely to be due to my project settings, or the external libs which are being linked in? Is it a common problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have incremental linking activated for debug builds and not for release builds. That is what is most probable. In the project settings you can have a look at Linker -> Command Line.

- `/INCREMENTAL` *.ilk file is generated to speed-up linking
- `/INCREMENTAL:NO` inactive

How to change the setting: Linker -> General -> Enable Incremental Linking

Answer (score 2):

It's more likely to be a more aggressive set of cross-object optimisations being applied to the release build.

Answer (score 1):

Several things to try:

- Turn on the more verbose linker settings: this may shed some light on what's going on
- Try linking without optimisation
- Do you have Whole Program Optimisation turned on?
- Download and run [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see which files it's spending time reading.  There could be some strange anomaly such as the release build using a slow network drive